# How to store a file directly in certain continuous disk blocks in Linux with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel

I am making a small simply storage system consisting of 16+ HDDs. All the files I need to store are 100MB ~ 1GB. It makes a big fuss over a minor issue to employ a complete file system. All I need is to store them into 
`/dev/sd[bcd...]` and remember where they are stored in case to read.

Write()/fwrite() would have system buffer and file system involved, I think? How can I skip the file system and store a file directly in certainly continuous disk blocks with C/C++ efficiently, just like `dd`?

Comment: A file is stored in the filesytem. dd does the same.

Comment: You can bypass the block cache on `open()` by setting the `O_DIRECT` flag (if it is supported by the file-system driver).

Comment: What makes you think that the file system is not "efficient" here?

Comment: Source code of `dd` which you mentioned, might have some hints. `dd_copy` function can be a good starting point: http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/dd.c#2039

Comment: Filesystems generally prefer contiguous blocks, except if you append multiple times (which is fully in your control), or if they do transparent compression (and why do you care about that?)

Comment: How big are your files: terabytes or gigabytes or petabytes??

Comment: @mldssr: could you please **edit your question** to improve it: explain how large are your files and what kind of application are you coding!

Comment: Even with the edit, you don't explain enough your context (e.g. total volume of data, number of files) and application (is it video, web server, ...).... But 16 disks to keep a few hundred files of a few giogabytes each is overkill.

Comment: If your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199135/how-to-design-a-driver-for-this-storage-system) you should have mentioned it. But all your questions still lack context and motivation (what kind of application are you developing, what industry, what data volume)....

Answer (score 3):

The [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) is *improving* performance, so you don't want to bypass it (or file system and other layers in the kernel). BTW, you are wrong in believing that `dd` would bypass them (and you could [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) some `dd` command to check), since `dd` is using (like your applications) [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html))

You could read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (both are freely downloadable) to understand that more.

BTW, when creating a file system (e.g. `mkefs`) you can tune parameters like block size (e.g. `-b` option to [mke2fs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html)...); perhaps you might recreate your file system with a larger block size (but that won't matter a lot).

You could dedicate a disk partition to your application (but you probably *should not*). See [raw(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/raw.8.html) -probably deprecated- and [sd(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/sd.4.html). Then format your disk and access e.g. `/dev/sdb3` as a block device from your code. But again, this is often unwise.

Notice that these days applications rarely use raw disk partition. As an example, consider RDBMS such as PostGreSQL or MySQL. In the 1980s they generally used raw disk partitions, today they are using large disk *files* (so the file overhead does not matter) and routinely manage datasets of many terabytes.

If you care about performance, I recommend instead to use a large buffer (e.g. a megabyte or some of them, not a kilobyte) for [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) operations, perhaps with the [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) (and even the [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html)) system call. Using `O_DIRECT` to [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (mentioned in [Maxim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46327381/841108)) would bypass the page cache so could slow down things (even if in some cases it could slightly speed up). Look also [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html). In some (but not all) cases accessing a file thru memory mapping with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) could be useful. Benchmark to find out the good buffer size for your particular application and computer (including hardware).

But you won't get miracles: the bottleneck is probably the disk hardware itself (not the file system or any other software layer). If possible, buy more RAM (to have a better [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)) and get a fast SSD.

Maybe (or probably) you should consider using RDBMS (PosGresSQL, MySQL), or non-SQL DBMS (MongoDb, ....), or libraries like [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) or [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/). They are well tuned and support many terabytes.

For huge datasets (petabytes), you are likely to redesign your application, buy/use/develop specialized hardware and software and hire experts (but then you won't ask here). For large content (terabytes), using files is sensible, and big files of several terabytes are well managed today. If you have lots -e.g. millions- of files (each of small size) you may want to organize them in directory trees (e.g. rather long paths like `dir01/subdir234/file4566`); if possible avoid huge directories (e.g. of many thousand files). I see no reason to want contiguous disk blocks, since file systems manage that very well today.

BTW, on current disk hardware (both spinning & SSD), "contiguous" blocks  don't mean much....

Look also for inspiration into existing code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) applications similar to yours.

<sup>Note. I am guessing that by "large files" you mean something which can be kept on a single disk (so a few terabytes at most).</sup>

> All the files I need to store are 100MB ~ 1GB.

These are actually quite small (or at least medium sized) files, and they would likely sit entirely in RAM (in the page cache, see also http://linuxatemyram.com/ ...). So you really should not bother, and of course you'll better keep them as plain files in some ordinary file system (no need to tune anything in practice).

> All I need is to store them into `/dev/sd[bcd...]` and remember where they are stored in case to read.

It seems you think of bypassing the file system, use some raw disk partition, and painfully mimic the role of a file system in your user-land code. In short, **don't do that** (remember that file systems are extremely well designed and tuned system code in the kernel; you won't do as well in only a few months of work).  It could even be worse (because you won't use the page cache as efficiently as your system does). Keep your data as ordinary file in ordinary file systems.
(Life is short, don't reinvent the wheel!).

> I am making a small simply storage system consisting of 16+ HDDs.

Perhaps you want an [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) and/or some [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID). I'm surprised you mention a small thing with more than 16 disks (perhaps buying fewer, but larger, disks might be better). BTW, 16 disks to keep a few dozen files of a  few gigabytes each is really overkill (since that fits in *one* terabyte disk). Don't forget to have *enough RAM!* And *don't forget backups!*

Remember that CPUs are many thousands times [faster](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) than disks (even SSDs). So almost always file system software layer overhead don't matter at all. Probably your code is I/O bound, not CPU bound, so optimizing your code for CPU is useless (however, tuning buffer sizes etc... is worthwhile, but you should benchmark).

<sup>P.S. it is a pity that you are asking [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199135/how-to-design-a-driver-for-this-storage-system) questions related to the same task, but don't give enough context, motivation, and details (what volume & bandwidth of data, what computer, what kind of application and code, what domain and industry, etc ...). I'm sure that with better and more detailed questions -as long as this answer- you'll get better and more useful answers.</sup>

Comment: I was under impression that `O_DIRECT` is often used by databases. For example, MySQL InnoDB opens data files with `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Probably useful for very large files. But OP have small (gigabyte sized) ones

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this.

The point of the various system and library calls, and of the whole idea of a filesystem, is to present to a program an *abstraction* of the various messy details involved in storing bytes on disk. There is no unix-standard way of getting below this, and opening up the abstraction.

It's conceivable that there is some back-door API to the inner workings of some filesystems, but I doubt it.  There be (very bad-tempered) dragons.

If you're concerned with high-bandwidth access to storage, then you should look instead at whatever tuning opportunities your filesystem offers, and consider changing the filesystem, or other storage solution, that you're using.  That's a big project, which I wouldn't want to offer advice on.

Answer (score 1):

Using `O_DIRECT` when `open`ing file bypasses the page cache in the kernel.

It must be supported by the filesystem. And you must satisfy the constraints specified in `man open(2)` when using `O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Probably bypassing the page cache would slow down the system (in  the OP's context)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would benchmark to find that out.